# Unable to override vm.args in rebar generated release

Tags: templates, parameters, erlang

I'm trying to override the configuration of a release made using Rebar. I'd like to *automatically* modify the vm.args file to use an `-sname chat` parameter to the VM, rather than the default `-name chat@127.0.0.1`.

If I understand it correctly, the subdirectory `files` contains versions of the configuration files that will be copied into a release directory when I use `rebar create-node nodeid=chat`. I am not forcing an overwrite, and I've modified the version in files with the values I want to use. It doesn't make it through to the release. Whenever I recreate the release, it overwrites the file `./etc/vm.args` with default values. Am I using rebar incorrectly?

Here's what I've been doing (in a Makefile) to generate the release:

```
gen-rel:
    rm -rf ./rel/*
    rebar create-node nodeid=chat
    rebar generate

start:
    ./rel/chat/bin/chat start

stop:
    ./rel/chat/bin/chat stop

ping:
    ./rel/chat/bin/chat ping

rebuild: stop compile gen-rel start ping
```

PS: Is this how I'm supposed to be building and debugging using rebar? I have another node that I want to connect to this with, and I assumed that creating and running the release is the quickest and easiest way to get my release reachable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `create-node` rebar subcommand should only be run once, rather than every time before `generate`. If you remove `create-node` line from your `gen-rel` make target and edit the `rel/files/vm.args` files with your overrides then you should find the generated release will now contain your overrides.

Recap steps:

1. Remove `rebar create-node nodeid=chat` line from your make file (just run it once).
2. Update the `rel/files/vm.args` file with your override(s).
3. Run `make rebuild`.
4. Commit your rel/files override changes into your SCM/VCS repository before you lose them;)

HTH

Comment: where this file vm.args is located mate